# Unable to convert a string to DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Inside a function, **I need to find the difference between 2 dates in seconds**. If the difference is more than 30 seconds i return **False** otherwise it returns **True** , first one I read it from database and Second one is the current DateTime.Now

Here is the snippest of code I'm using that does the work while `dr.GetValue(0).ToString()` holds the current value in the database :

```
if (dr.Read())
            {

                DateTime nowDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt"));
                DateTime then = DateTime.ParseExact(dr.GetValue(0).ToString(), "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                TimeSpan diff = nowDate - then;

                int timeDifference = diff.Seconds;


                if (timeDifference > 30)
                {
                    myConn.Dispose();
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    myConn.Dispose();
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

When i execute the code above i get a message error :
 `string was not recognized as valid DateTime`

And here is the line that is causing the error :

```
 DateTime then = DateTime.ParseExact(dr.GetValue(0).ToString(), "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The time is stored in the database in this format : `2013-02-18 14:06:37`

But when I execute the following line (for debugging purposes) :

```
MessageBox.Show(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

I see a message box that shows the date in this format : `2/18/2013 2:06:37 PM`

How to find the difference in seconds between the current time and the time stored in dr.GetValue(0).ToString()

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Why are you using strings for `DateTimes`? Use parameters.

Comment: Why are you converting `DateTime.Now` into a string and then back into a `DateTime`? Why aren't you returning a `DateTime` from your database query?

Comment: isn't your datetime in your database, well, a datetime?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to get the DateTime from database (the columln type in db is DATETIME)

Comment: @ShikataGaNai Simple - `reader.GetDateTime(0)`

Comment: When you are using AM/PM format, change `H` to `h`.

Comment: Why are you doing `DateTime nowDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt"));`? and why not use `dr.GetDateTime(0);` instead of all the converting and parsing?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `h`, not `H`. `h` is the hour in 12-hour format, `H` is the hour in 24-hour format. Since your example hour is `2 PM` (not `14 PM`) it's the 12-hour format you want.

Also:

- You're converting your now-time to a string and back - don't bother!
- You're counting `Seconds` not `TotalSeconds` - this is incorrect because e.g. a 60-second period gives a `Seconds` value of `0`.

```
DateTime nowDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime then = DateTime.ParseExact(
    dr.GetValue(0).ToString(), "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

TimeSpan diff = nowDate - then;

double secondsDifference = diff.TotalSeconds;
```

You should even be able to do something along the lines of

```
DateTime then = dr.GetDateTime(0);
```

and avoid the string-parsing altogether, but the `H`/`h` difference is the reason you get the specific exception you asked about.

Answer (score 1):

if, as it looks like, your date is a datetime in the database, you can probably simplify the two lines to this:

```
DateTime nowDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime then = (DateTime)dr.GetValue(0);
```

(although I'm making a lot of assumptions here)

Answer (score 1):

Your code really should be very simple:

```
if (dr.Read())
{
    DateTime then = dr.GetDateTime(0);
    TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - then;
    int timeDifference = diff.TotalSeconds;
}
```

One thing to note - you really shouldn't be calling `myConn.Dispose();` in your `if/else`. Wrap your connection and readers in a `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think your server has Application server has some other date format set. What you can try is this:

```
Convert.ToDate(value,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormate);
```

Hope this will solve the error.Haven't tested it so hope for best